# VueJS - Run Code after event is successfully emitted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, eventemitter

I'm trying to clear up the form in the child component after the event containing the entered form data has been successfully passed from the child to parent component. However, I notice that the form gets cleared before the data gets propagated via the event to the parent component, such that the event passes empty values to the parent. I tried delaying the clearForm() using a timeout, but it didn't help. Is there a way to modify the behavior such that the clearForm() happens only after the event completes and the data has been saved?

Attached is the code.

**Child Component**

```
<template>
    <!-- Contains a form -- >
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
    data() {
        return {
            additionalInfo: 
                {
                    id: new Date().toISOString(),
                    fullName: '',
                    preAuthorize: '',
                    serviceAddress: ''
                },
            validation: {
                fullNameIsValid: true,
                serviceAddressIsValid: true
            },
            formIsValid: true,
            addServiceButtonText: '+ Add Service Notes (Optional)',
            serviceNotes: [],
            showServiceNotes: false,
            enteredServiceNote: '', //service notes addendum
        }
    },
    computed : {
        // something
    },
    methods: {
        
        setServiceNotes(){
            this.showServiceNotes = !this.showServiceNotes;
        },
        addAnotherParty(){
            this.validateForm();
            if(!this.formIsValid){
                return;
            }
            this.$emit('add-parties', this.additionalInfo); //event
            console.log(this.clearForm);
        },
        
        clearForm(){
            this.additionalInfo.fullName = '';
            this.additionalInfo.serviceAddress = '';
            this.additionalInfo.preAuthorize = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <base-card 
        ref="childComponent"
        @add-parties="updateAdditionalInfoList">
            <!-- Wrapper for the `Parties Being Served` component-->
                <template v-slot:title>
                    <slot></slot>
                </template>

        </base-card>
    </div>
    
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            hasElement: false,
            selectedComponent: 'base-card',
            additionalInfoList : [],
            clearForm: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateAdditionalInfoList(additionalInfo){ //save changes passed via event
            this.additionalInfoList.push(additionalInfo);
            console.log('emitted');
            console.log(this.additionalInfoList);    
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.$refs.childComponent.clearForm();  //clear the form in child
            }, 2000);
            
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
addAnotherParty(){
  this.validateForm();
  if(!this.formIsValid){
    return;
  }
  let emitObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.additionalInfo));
  this.$emit('add-parties', emitObj); //event
  console.log(this.clearForm);
}
```

If your object is not deep then you can use

```
let emitObj = Object.assign({}, this.additionalInfo);
```

instead of stringify and parse

Comment: thanks. It works like a charm now. Mind me asking how the use of JSON caused the event to complete before the form clear?

Comment: You cannot assign the object without reference in JS. So whatever you changed in assigned object it will be reflected to the variable you used to assign.

Object.assign will create a shallow copy with new reference only for first hierarchy. but JSON.stringify will create a completely new reference since you are converting to string.. and parse another you get another reference but as object.

Same applies to Array in JS